# machine learning libraries in s+ (or R)?

Tags: r, machine-learning, libraries, s-plus

have been searching around the internet and stackoverflow, but haven't been able to find any information on libraries for machine learning in s-plus or R. does anyone know of any or could perhaps point me in the right direction? thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You should probably start at the [CRAN Task View on Machine Learning & Statistical Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html) which covers the [R](http://www.r-project.org) side.

Comment: thanks! do you (or anyone) happen to know of any libraries specifically for s+?

Comment: S+ (usually spelled with a capital S) hasn't been all that relevant in a while. Look at the tag count of this question: 2587 for r, 5 for s-plus.  But you may be able to port some of the R libraries -- open source allows you to poke a stick at it and try this.

Answer (score 2):

this one maybe helpful:[machine learning open source software Filter by Programming Language](http://mloss.org/software/language/r/)

Answer (score 0):

If your interest in ML on R includes classification and regression algorithms, then you will want to explore [CARET](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html). Be advised that, in a [recent evaluation](http://glennengstrand.info/software/architecture/ml/oss),  I found the R offerings quite underwhelming when compared to the other ML OSS.